# Perlin Noise Generation not functioning properly

Tags: java, perlin-noise

I have been working with perlin noise recently and when implementing it into a tile engine I am using, I have noticed that the perlin noise function produced "blocks" as seen in the picture below. Each pixel is another different location in a 500 by 500 array that is returned from the perlin noise function.

in this example the persistence is 0.5 with an octave count of 5
[image]

When playing with it further, the more octaves I have, the larger the block chunks.

Here is the Code that I am using to call the perlin noise function:

```
PerlinNoise p = new PerlinNoise();
//returns a float[][] array of 500 by 500
p.GeneratePerlinNoise(p.genWhiteNoise(500, 500), 5, (float) 0.1);
```

PerlinNoise class

import java.util.Random;

```
public class PerlinNoise {
Random r;

public PerlinNoise() {
    r = new Random();
}

public void setSeed(long seed) {
    r.setSeed(seed);
}

public void printOutArray(float[][] arr) {
    for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        for(int n = 0; n < arr[0].length; n++) {
            System.out.print(arr[i][n] + ", "); 
        }
        System.out.print("\n");
    }
}

public void printOutTerrain(float[][] arr) {
    for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        for(int n = 0; n < arr[0].length; n++) {
            float a = arr[i][n];
            if(a < 0.4) {
                System.out.print("W"); 
            } else {
                System.out.print("L"); 
            }
        }
        System.out.print("\n");
    }
}

//-------------------------------------------------------------//

float[][] genWhiteNoise(int width, int height) {
    float[][] noise = new float[height][width];

    for(int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
        for(int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
            noise[y][x] = r.nextFloat();
        }
    }

    return noise;
}

float[][] genSmoothNoise(float[][] baseNoise, int octave) {
    int height = baseNoise.length;
    int width = baseNoise[0].length;

    float[][] smoothNoise = new float[height][width];

    int samplePeriod = 1 << octave; //calculates 2^k
    float sampleFrequency = (float) (1.0/samplePeriod);

    for(int i = 0; i < height; i++) {
        int sample_i0 = (i / samplePeriod) * samplePeriod;
        int sample_i1 = (sample_i0 + samplePeriod) % height; //wrap around
        float vertical_blend = (i - sample_i0) * sampleFrequency;

        for(int n = 0; n < width; n++) {
            int sample_n0 = (n / samplePeriod) * samplePeriod;
            int sample_n1 = (sample_n0 + samplePeriod) % width; //wrap around
            float horizontal_blend = (n - sample_n0) * sampleFrequency;

            //blend the top two corners
            float top = Interpolate(baseNoise[sample_i0][sample_n0],
                baseNoise[sample_i1][sample_n0], horizontal_blend);

            //blend the bottom two corners
            float bottom = Interpolate(baseNoise[sample_i0][sample_n1],
                baseNoise[sample_i1][sample_n1], horizontal_blend);

            //final blend
            smoothNoise[i][n] = Interpolate(top, bottom, vertical_blend);
        }
    }

    return smoothNoise;
}

float[][] GeneratePerlinNoise(float[][] baseNoise, int octaveCount, float persistance)
{
   int height = baseNoise.length;
   int width = baseNoise[0].length;

   float[][][] smoothNoise = new float[octaveCount][][]; //an array of 2D arrays containing

   //generate smooth noise
   for (int i = 0; i < octaveCount; i++)
   {
       smoothNoise[i] = genSmoothNoise(baseNoise, i);
   }

    float[][] perlinNoise = new float[height][width];
    float amplitude = 1.0f;
    float totalAmplitude = 0.0f;

    //blend noise together
    for (int octave = octaveCount - 1; octave >= 0; octave--)
    {
       amplitude *= persistance;
       totalAmplitude += amplitude;

       for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
       {
          for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
          {
             perlinNoise[i][j] += smoothNoise[octave][i][j] * amplitude;
          }
       }
    }

   //normalisation
   for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
   {
      for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
      {
         perlinNoise[i][j] /= totalAmplitude;
      }
   }

   return perlinNoise;
}

//linear average between two points
float Interpolate(float x0, float x1, float alpha)
{
    return Cosine_Interpolate(x0, x1, alpha);
}

//Linear Interpolation
float Linear_Interpolate(float x0, float x1, float alpha)
{
    return x0 * (1 - alpha) + alpha * x1;
}

//Cosine interpolation (much smoother)
float Cosine_Interpolate(float x0, float x1, float alpha)
{
    float ft = (float) (alpha * 3.141592653589);
    float f = (float) ((1 - Math.cos(ft)) * 0.5);

    return x0*(1-f) + x1*f;
}


}
```

So to reiterate my question: Why is my perlin noise function behaving the way it does, as in only generating space in chunks?

Comment: Asking people to spot errors in your code is not especially productive.  You should use the debugger (or add print statements) to isolate the problem, by tracing the progress of your program, and comparing it to what you expect to happen.  As soon as the two diverge, then you've found your problem.   (And then if necessary, you should construct a [minimal test-case](http://sscce.org).)

Answer (score 4):

So to fix this, all I had to do is swap the vertical_blend and horizontal_blend variables in the genSmoothNoise() method. It's amazing what you notice after a break